# CUDA: Reduce algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, cuda, parallel-processing, reduce

I am new to **C++/CUDA**. I tried implementing the parallel algorithm "**reduce**" with ability to handle any type of inputsize, and threadsize without increasing asymptotic parallel runtime by recursing over the output of the kernel (in the *kernel wrapper*).

e.g. [Implementing Max Reduce in Cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371275/implementing-max-reduce-in-cuda) the top answer to this question, his/hers implementation will essentially be sequential when threadsize is small enough.

However, I keep getting a "**Segmentation fault**" when I compile and run it ..?

```
>> nvcc -o mycode mycode.cu
>> ./mycode
Segmentail fault.
```

Compiled on a K40 with cuda 6.5

Here is the *kernel*, basically same as the SO post I linked the checker for "out of bounds" is different:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* -------- KERNEL -------- */
__global__ void reduce_kernel(float * d_out, float * d_in, const int size)
{
  // position and threadId
  int pos = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int tid = threadIdx.x;

  // do reduction in global memory
  for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x / 2; s>0; s>>=1)
  {
    if (tid < s)
    {
      if (pos+s < size) // Handling out of bounds
      {
        d_in[pos] = d_in[pos] + d_in[pos+s];
      }
    }
  }

  // only thread 0 writes result, as thread
  if (tid==0)
  {
    d_out[blockIdx.x] = d_in[pos];
  }
}
```

The *kernel wrapper* I mentioned to handle when 1 block will not contain all of the data.

```
/* -------- KERNEL WRAPPER -------- */
void reduce(float * d_out, float * d_in, const int size, int num_threads)
{
  // setting up blocks and intermediate result holder
  int num_blocks = ((size) / num_threads) + 1;
  float * d_intermediate;
  cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks);

  // recursively solving, will run approximately log base num_threads times.
  do
  {
    reduce_kernel<<<num_blocks, num_threads>>>(d_intermediate, d_in, size);

    // updating input to intermediate
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    // Updating num_blocks to reflect how many blocks we now want to compute on
      num_blocks = num_blocks / num_threads + 1;

    // updating intermediate
    cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks);
  }
  while(num_blocks > num_threads); // if it is too small, compute rest.

  // computing rest
  reduce_kernel<<<1, num_blocks>>>(d_out, d_in, size);

}
```

Main program to initialize in/out and create bogus data for testing.

```
/* -------- MAIN -------- */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Setting num_threads
  int num_threads = 512;
  // Making bogus data and setting it on the GPU
  const int size = 1024;
  const int size_out = 1;
  float * d_in;
  float * d_out;
  cudaMalloc(&d_in, sizeof(float)*size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, sizeof(float)*size_out);
  const int value = 5;
  cudaMemset(d_in, value, sizeof(float)*size);

  // Running kernel wrapper
  reduce(d_out, d_in, size, num_threads);

  printf("sum is element is: %.f", d_out[0]);
}
```

Comment: A segmentation fault arises out of host code, not CUDA device code.  Good practice when asking about a segmentation fault on SO is to identify the line that is causing the fault (a seg fault can always be localized to a specific line of code that actually generates the fault).  This localization could be done trivially with `printf` statements scattered throughout the code, or via a debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things I would point out with your code.

1. As a general rule/boilerplate, I always recommend using [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, any time you are having trouble with a cuda code.  However those methods wouldn't help much with the seg fault, although they may help later (see below).
2. The actual seg fault is occurring on this line:

   ```
   printf("sum is element is: %.f", d_out[0]);
   ```

   you've broken a cardinal CUDA programming rule: host pointers must not be dereferenced in device code, and device pointers must not be dereferenced in host code.  This latter condition applies here.  `d_out` is a device pointer (allocated via `cudaMalloc`).  Such pointers have *no meaning* if you attempt to dereference them in host code, and doing so will lead to a seg fault.

   The solution is to copy the data back to the host before printing it out:

   ```
   float result;
   cudaMemcpy(&result, d_out, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   printf("sum is element is: %.f", result);
   ```
3. Using `cudaMalloc` in a loop, on the same variable, without doing any `cudaFree` operations, is not good practice, and may lead to out-of-memory errors in long-running loops, and may also lead to programs with memory leaks, if such a construct is used in a larger program:

   ```
   do
   {
     ...

     cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks);
   }
   while...
   ```

   in this case I think a better approach and trivial fix would be to `cudaFree` `d_intermediate` right before you re-allocate:

   ```
   do
   {
     ...
     cudaFree(d_intermediate);
     cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks);
   }
   while...
   ```
4. This might not be doing what you think it is:

   ```
   const int value = 5;
   cudaMemset(d_in, value, sizeof(float)*size);
   ```

   probably you are aware of this, but `cudaMemset`, like `memset`, operates on byte quantities.  So you are filling the `d_in` array with a value corresponding to `0x05050505` (and I have no idea what that bit pattern corresponds to when interpreted as a `float` quantity).  Since you refer to bogus values, you may be cognizant of this already.  But it's a common error (e.g. if you were actually trying to initialize the array with the value of 5 in every `float` location), so I thought I would point it out.

Your code has other issues as well (which you will discover if you make the above fixes then run your code with `cuda-memcheck`).  To learn about how to do good parallel reductions, I would recommend studying the CUDA parallel reduction [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) and [presentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).  Parallel reductions in global memory are not recommended for performance reasons.

For completeness, here are some of the additional issues I found:

1. Your kernel code needs an appropriate `__syncthreads()` statement to ensure that the work of all threads in a block are complete before any threads go onto the next iteration of the for-loop.
2. Your final write to global memory in the kernel needs to also be conditioned on the read-location being in-bounds.  Otherwise, your strategy of always launching an extra block would allow the read from this line to be out-of-bounds (`cuda-memcheck` will show this).
3. The reduction logic in your loop in the `reduce` function is generally messed up and needed to be re-worked in several ways.

I'm not saying this code is defect-free, but it seems to work for the given test case and produce the correct answer (1024):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* -------- KERNEL -------- */
__global__ void reduce_kernel(float * d_out, float * d_in, const int size)
{
  // position and threadId
  int pos = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int tid = threadIdx.x;

  // do reduction in global memory
  for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x / 2; s>0; s>>=1)
  {
    if (tid < s)
    {
      if (pos+s < size) // Handling out of bounds
      {
        d_in[pos] = d_in[pos] + d_in[pos+s];
      }
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }

  // only thread 0 writes result, as thread
  if ((tid==0) && (pos < size))
  {
    d_out[blockIdx.x] = d_in[pos];
  }
}

/* -------- KERNEL WRAPPER -------- */
void reduce(float * d_out, float * d_in, int size, int num_threads)
{
  // setting up blocks and intermediate result holder
  int num_blocks = ((size) / num_threads) + 1;
  float * d_intermediate;
  cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks);
  cudaMemset(d_intermediate, 0, sizeof(float)*num_blocks);
  int prev_num_blocks;
  // recursively solving, will run approximately log base num_threads times.
  do
  {
    reduce_kernel<<<num_blocks, num_threads>>>(d_intermediate, d_in, size);

    // updating input to intermediate
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    // Updating num_blocks to reflect how many blocks we now want to compute on
      prev_num_blocks = num_blocks;
      num_blocks = num_blocks / num_threads + 1;

    // updating intermediate
    cudaFree(d_intermediate);
    cudaMalloc(&d_intermediate, sizeof(float)*num_blocks);
    size = num_blocks*num_threads;
  }
  while(num_blocks > num_threads); // if it is too small, compute rest.

  // computing rest
  reduce_kernel<<<1, prev_num_blocks>>>(d_out, d_in, prev_num_blocks);

}

/* -------- MAIN -------- */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Setting num_threads
  int num_threads = 512;
  // Making non-bogus data and setting it on the GPU
  const int size = 1024;
  const int size_out = 1;
  float * d_in;
  float * d_out;
  cudaMalloc(&d_in, sizeof(float)*size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, sizeof(float)*size_out);
  //const int value = 5;
  //cudaMemset(d_in, value, sizeof(float)*size);
  float * h_in = (float *)malloc(size*sizeof(float));
  for (int i = 0; i <  size; i++) h_in[i] = 1.0f;
  cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, sizeof(float)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Running kernel wrapper
  reduce(d_out, d_in, size, num_threads);
  float result;
  cudaMemcpy(&result, d_out, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("sum is element is: %.f\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you put a lot of effort into this. This helped me a lot in understanding cuda and parallelization. I further swapped "num_blocks" with "prev_num_blocks" in the while condition to obtain another round of parallerization. Thanks.